# Failed to load config "prettier" to extend from.(Previous reference of this question didn't help)

Tags: reactjs, eslint, ethereum, eslint-plugin-react, eslint-plugin-import

```
npx create-react-app react-dapp
npm install ethers hardhat @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers
npx hardhat
```

After excuting the above command I faced the followings

Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module
'eslint-plugin-prettier'
Require stack:
- /home/tahmid/latest_projects/Etherium/Etherium_Transactions/React_Etherium/react-
dapp/node_modules/react-scripts/config/**placeholder**.js
Referenced from:
/home/tahmid/latest_projects/Etherium/Etherium_Transactions/React_Etherium/react-
dapp/.eslintrc.js

To solve this error I used the following-

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-prettier
```

Then this occurred-

```
Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 
'eslint-plugin-prettier'
Require stack:
- /home/tahmid/latest_projects/Etherium/Etherium_Transactions/React_Etherium/react- 
dapp/node_modules/react-scripts/config/__placeholder__.js
```

Referenced from:
/home/tahmid/latest_projects/Etherium/Etherium_Transactions/React_Etherium/react-
dapp/.eslintrc.js

to solve it
added `"eslint": "^5.8.0",` this to my package.json
and execute this command - `npm i eslint-plugin-prettier`

then occured -

```
src/App.js
  Line 1:1:   Import and export declarations are not supported yet  node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
  Line 1:18:  Replace `'./logo.svg'` with `"./logo.svg"`            prettier/prettier
  Line 2:1:   Import and export declarations are not supported yet  node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
  Line 2:8:   Replace `'./App.css'` with `"./App.css"`              prettier/prettier
  Line 25:1:  Import and export declarations are not supported yet  node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax

src/index.js
  Line 1:1:    Import and export declarations are not supported yet      node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
  Line 1:19:   Replace `'react'` with `"react"`                          prettier/prettier
  Line 2:1:    Import and export declarations are not supported yet      node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
  Line 2:22:   Replace `'react-dom'` with `"react-dom"`                  prettier/prettier
  Line 3:1:    Import and export declarations are not supported yet      node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
  Line 3:8:    Replace `'./index.css'` with `"./index.css"`              prettier/prettier
  Line 4:1:    Import and export declarations are not supported yet      node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
  Line 4:17:   Replace `'./App'` with `"./App"`                          prettier/prettier
  Line 5:1:    Import and export declarations are not supported yet      node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
  Line 5:29:   Replace `'./reportWebVitals'` with `"./reportWebVitals"`  prettier/prettier
  Line 11:27:  Replace `'root'` with `"root"`                            prettier/prettier

src/reportWebVitals.js
  Line 1:25:  Replace `onPerfEntry` with `(onPerfEntry)`            prettier/prettier
  Line 3:12:  Replace `'web-vitals'` with `"web-vitals"`            prettier/prettier
  Line 13:1:  Import and export declarations are not supported yet  node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

so I installed this

```
npm i eslint-plugin-import
```

and nothing changed

Now I am totally clueless what to do next

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-dapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.2",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",
    "ethers": "^5.4.7",
    "hardhat": "^2.6.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "standardx": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-standard": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0"
    
  },
  "ts-standard": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  }
  
}
```

eslint-plugin-prettier.js

```
> /**  * @fileoverview Runs `prettier` as an ESLint rule.  * @author
> Andres Suarez  */
> 
> 'use strict';
> 
> //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //  Requirements //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> const {   showInvisibles,   generateDifferences, } =
> require('prettier-linter-helpers');
> 
> //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //  Constants //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> const { INSERT, DELETE, REPLACE } = generateDifferences;
> 
> //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //  Privates //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> // Lazily-loaded Prettier. /**  * @type {import('prettier')}  */ let
> prettier;
> 
> //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //  Rule Definition //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> /**  * Reports a difference.  * @param
> {import('eslint').Rule.RuleContext} context - The ESLint rule context.
> * @param {import('prettier-linter-helpers').Difference} difference - The difference object.  * @returns {void}  */ function
> reportDifference(context, difference) {   const { operation, offset,
> deleteText = '', insertText = '' } = difference;   const range =
> [offset, offset + deleteText.length];   const [start, end] =
> range.map((index) =>
>     context.getSourceCode().getLocFromIndex(index)   );
> 
>   context.report({
>     messageId: operation,
>     data: {
>       deleteText: showInvisibles(deleteText),
>       insertText: showInvisibles(insertText),
>     },
>     loc: { start, end },
>     fix: (fixer) => fixer.replaceTextRange(range, insertText),   }); }
> 
> //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //  Module Definition //
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> module.exports = {   configs: {
>     recommended: {
>       extends: ['prettier'],
>       plugins: ['prettier'],
>       rules: {
>         'prettier/prettier': 'error',
>         'arrow-body-style': 'off',
>         'prefer-arrow-callback': 'off',
>       },
>     },   },   rules: {
>     prettier: {
>       meta: {
>         docs: {
>           url: 'https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#options',
>         },
>         type: 'layout',
>         fixable: 'code',
>         schema: [
>           // Prettier options:
>           {
>             type: 'object',
>             properties: {},
>             additionalProperties: true,
>           },
>           {
>             type: 'object',
>             properties: {
>               usePrettierrc: { type: 'boolean' },
>               fileInfoOptions: {
>                 type: 'object',
>                 properties: {},
>                 additionalProperties: true,
>               },
>             },
>             additionalProperties: true,
>           },
>         ],
>         messages: {
>           [INSERT]: 'Insert `{{ insertText }}`',
>           [DELETE]: 'Delete `{{ deleteText }}`',
>           [REPLACE]: 'Replace `{{ deleteText }}` with `{{ insertText }}`',
>         },
>       },
>       create(context) {
>         const usePrettierrc =
>           !context.options[1] || context.options[1].usePrettierrc !== false;
>         const eslintFileInfoOptions =
>           (context.options[1] && context.options[1].fileInfoOptions) || {};
>         const sourceCode = context.getSourceCode();
>         const filepath = context.getFilename();
>         // Processors that extract content from a file, such as the markdown
>         // plugin extracting fenced code blocks may choose to specify virtual
>         // file paths. If this is the case then we need to resolve prettier
>         // config and file info using the on-disk path instead of the virtual
>         // path.
>         const onDiskFilepath = context.getPhysicalFilename();
>         const source = sourceCode.text;
> 
>         return {
>           Program() {
>             if (!prettier) {
>               // Prettier is expensive to load, so only load it if needed.
>               prettier = require('prettier');
>             }
> 
>             const eslintPrettierOptions = context.options[0] || {};
> 
>             const prettierRcOptions = usePrettierrc
>               ? prettier.resolveConfig.sync(onDiskFilepath, {
>                   editorconfig: true,
>                 })
>               : null;
> 
>             const { ignored, inferredParser } = prettier.getFileInfo.sync(
>               onDiskFilepath,
>               Object.assign(
>                 {},
>                 { resolveConfig: true, ignorePath: '.prettierignore' },
>                 eslintFileInfoOptions
>               )
>             );
> 
>             // Skip if file is ignored using a .prettierignore file
>             if (ignored) {
>               return;
>             }
> 
>             const initialOptions = {};
> 
>             // ESLint supports processors that let you extract and lint JS
>             // fragments within a non-JS language. In the cases where prettier
>             // supports the same language as a processor, we want to process
>             // the provided source code as javascript (as ESLint provides the
>             // rules with fragments of JS) instead of guessing the parser
>             // based off the filename. Otherwise, for instance, on a .md file we
>             // end up trying to run prettier over a fragment of JS using the
>             // markdown parser, which throws an error.
>             // Processors may set virtual filenames for these extracted blocks.
>             // If they do so then we want to trust the file extension they
>             // provide, and no override is needed.
>             // If the processor does not set any virtual filename (signified by
>             // `filepath` and `onDiskFilepath` being equal) AND we can't
>             // infer the parser from the filename, either because no filename
>             // was provided or because there is no parser found for the
>             // filename, use javascript.
>             // This is added to the options first, so that
>             // prettierRcOptions and eslintPrettierOptions can still override
>             // the parser.
>             //
>             // `parserBlocklist` should contain the list of prettier parser
>             // names for file types where:
>             // * Prettier supports parsing the file type
>             // * There is an ESLint processor that extracts JavaScript snippets
>             //   from the file type.
>             const parserBlocklist = [null, 'markdown', 'html'];
> 
>             let inferParserToBabel =
>               parserBlocklist.indexOf(inferredParser) !== -1;
> 
>             if (
>               // it could be processed by `@graphql-eslint/eslint-plugin` or `eslint-plugin-graphql`
>               inferredParser === 'graphql' &&
>               // for `eslint-plugin-graphql`, see https://github.com/apollographql/eslint-plugin-graphql/blob/master/src/index.js#L416
>               source.startsWith('ESLintPluginGraphQLFile`')
>             ) {
>               inferParserToBabel = true;
>             }
> 
>             if (filepath === onDiskFilepath && inferParserToBabel) {
>               initialOptions.parser = 'babel';
>             }
> 
>             const prettierOptions = Object.assign(
>               {},
>               initialOptions,
>               prettierRcOptions,
>               eslintPrettierOptions,
>               { filepath }
>             );
> 
>             // prettier.format() may throw a SyntaxError if it cannot parse the
>             // source code it is given. Usually for JS files this isn't a
>             // problem as ESLint will report invalid syntax before trying to
>             // pass it to the prettier plugin. However this might be a problem
>             // for non-JS languages that are handled by a plugin. Notably Vue
>             // files throw an error if they contain unclosed elements, such as
>             // `<template><div></template>. In this case report an error at the
>             // point at which parsing failed.
>             let prettierSource;
>             try {
>               prettierSource = prettier.format(source, prettierOptions);
>             } catch (err) {
>               if (!(err instanceof SyntaxError)) {
>                 throw err;
>               }
> 
>               let message = 'Parsing error: ' + err.message;
> 
>               // Prettier's message contains a codeframe style preview of the
>               // invalid code and the line/column at which the error occurred.
>               // ESLint shows those pieces of information elsewhere already so
>               // remove them from the message
>               if (err.codeFrame) {
>                 message = message.replace(`\n${err.codeFrame}`, '');
>               }
>               if (err.loc) {
>                 message = message.replace(/ \(\d+:\d+\)$/, '');
>               }
> 
>               context.report({ message, loc: err.loc });
> 
>               return;
>             }
> 
>             if (source !== prettierSource) {
>               const differences = generateDifferences(source, prettierSource);
> 
>               for (const difference of differences) {
>                 reportDifference(context, difference);
>               }
>             }
>           },
>         };
>       },
>     },   }, };
```

App.js

```
  import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```